# The two sides of this 'or' pattern bind different sets of variables?

Tags: f#

The following code try to combine two match cases `None` and `Some s when s <= aDate` (Do "part 1" if date is None or date <= aDate).

```
match date with
| None 
| Some s when s <= aDate -> 
    ..... // Part 1
| _ -> 
    .....
```

However it get the error? How to avoid rewrite "Part 1" twice?

> The two sides of this 'or' pattern bind different sets of variables

The following code works.

```
match date with
| None ->
    ..... // Part 1
| Some s when s <= aDate -> 
    ..... // repeat Part 1
| _ -> 
    .....
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this because the `None` path cannot have access to `s`. I take it you don't use the value of `s` in `Part 1`?

Comment: No, `s` is not used in "Part 1". It's only used to constraint the match condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do that, for the reason explained by the compiler error.

However, you should be able to solve the duplication with an [active pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx):

```
let (|IsPart1|_|) aDate candidate =
    match candidate with
    | None -> Some ()
    | Some s when s <= aDate -> Some ()
    | _ -> None
```

This would enable you to write a function like this:

```
let foo date aDate =
    match date with
    | IsPart1 aDate -> "Part 1"
    | _ -> "Part 2"
```

Here are some FSI usage examples:

```
> let aDate = DateTime(2015, 7, 29);;    
val aDate : DateTime = 29.07.2015 00:00:00    
> foo None aDate;;
val it : string = "Part 1"
> foo (Some (DateTime(2011, 1, 1))) aDate;;
val it : string = "Part 1"
> foo (Some (DateTime(2015, 7, 30))) aDate;;
val it : string = "Part 2"
```

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, you could also 'invert' the branches:

```
match date with
| Some s when s > aDate -> 
    .....
| _ -> 
    ..... // Part 1
```

Answer (score -2):

You just forgot the arrow -> in the None case

```
match date with
| None ->
    ..... // Part 1
| Some s when s <= aDate -> 
    ..... // repeat Part 1
| _ -> 
    .....
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, the OP is trying to find a way to have to write the Part1 call once for both None and Some < aDate